# setting apache environment variable

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

My hosting environment using Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) and I am modifying 
./usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf to set environment variable and restarting the server .

SetEnv  XML-RPC-IPs 193.45.32.21

I did set it as a first entry in the file and restarted the server . But even restarting if I try to print it is still getting me black , Am I missing any thing ?

echo "My IP address ".$_SERVER['XML-RPC-IPs'];

Thanks for your help
Regards
Kiran

Comment: Go to serverfault.com, this is a programming site, you should certainly get an answer there

Comment: I know this may not help, but fyi I tried your exact code on my own server and it worked fine. I am also using Apache 2.2.14 (on Ubuntu Server). Maybe you have some configuration problem that prevents setting or reading envars?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer , I did check the php info . The variable is there , but surprisingly with different name I mean the name I gave is "XML-RPC-IPs' ( In between hyphens ) But that came as "XML_RPC_IP" ( In between underscores ) . Not sure why ...

Answer (score 1):

Environmental Variables are located in `$_ENV superglobal`.

What you are looking for is `echo "My IP address ".$_ENV['XML-RPC-IPs'];`